# Merge sql query same columns values into one array

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I've this simple query.

```
SELECT purchase.Quantity*purchase.Price AS Total FROM purchase.
```

In code-igniter I fetch the result as array by: `$this->db->query($query)->result_array();`

The query result is:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["Total"]=> string(2) "42" } [1]=> array(1) { ["Total"]=> string(5) "10900" } }
```

What I want is a single array Total, which contains all the values like

```
Total=[42,10900]
```

Is there anything I'm missing in my code or query?

Comment: do you need sum of all purchase?

Comment: nope. I need to multiply two columns

Comment: `$output = array_map(function($v){ return $v['Total']; }, $result);` ?

Comment: I am not sure what your exact need is but if you want the grant total you can use `SUM(purchase.Quantity*purchase.Price) AS Total`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is easily achievable by using a `foreach` loop. If I understood correctly..

```
$total = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
   $total[] = $row['Total'];
}
print_r($total); // outputs something like this: Array (  [0] => 42 [1] => 10900  )
```

Comment: what if i dont know the property name as in here its TOTAL?

Comment: I don't understand how you can't know the name of the column...?

Comment: what If it decides at runtime.

Comment: Total can be a TotalPurchase maybe

Comment: Could it be only Total or TotalPurchase?